# Handle 503 response in the client

Tags: reactjs, web, client, http-status-code-503

I'm working with some public api, and sometimes i get from this api 503 response - i understood that it because the server is temporarily unable to handle a request(overload).

And i would like to know what is the best practise to handle this situation in the client(React), because i know that if i will send the request again i will get a valid data.

- do i need to continue sending request with some timeout? or i need to throw and say to the user to load again?
  Any help will be perfect

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to handle the case, and usually it depends on project requirements to decide.
So yes, one way to handle this it to repeat request. There are few thing to take into account: you don't want to spam requests to service that already having trouble, so you might want to limit the amount of retries and use exponential function (each next retry wait longer). If you use axois you can try [axios-retry](https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry), or it's not hard to implement some wrapper around fetch.
Also it's possible to delegate this decision to user - i.e. show some error and retry button.

Answer (score 0):

In case of "If I will send the request again, I will get a valid data". I would suggest you to send the request again with some timeout.

As you know you're going to get the valid data if you send the request again, then this would rather make sense than asking user to reload the page again.

And by the time request is fetching the data, you can display loading to the user.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you must let user know the situation as a warning and in the background try to get the data for each 5 or 10 seconds (your choice).

On backend side you can check out "circuit breakers" for this approach.

If you are developing a mobile app or PWA (if you have local managed data) you can manage your changes in your local store and when connection established, then synchronize your local data with your api (if your backend provides this).